# Connecting band heaters to power source

Tags: power-supply

Hello and thank you for having me.
My question is about connecting a heating band, for injection molding machines, to a temperature controlled outlet.

The temp controller is a
Ketotek model KT8230
Power supply AC120V +/- 10%
OUTPUT RELAY MAX 30/250V

The heating band is from Amazon.
BestTong 110V 380W 35mmx35mm Injected Mould Heating Element Brass Band Heater for Injection Molding Machine
There is also a stainless steel version for half the price.

My plan is to connect the outlet to a contact relay which will be connected to the Ketotek to activate/deactivate coil. So the relay handles the current and the Ketotek maintains a temp range that I set.
I have done all this for in wall fan forced heaters and with in wall timers before.

Can I connect the heating band directly to the outlet, that is being controlled by the Ketotek? Or will I need some kind of resisters/capacitor etc. circuitry to keep the breaker from tripping?
Also... should I use 240 or 120 band heaters? I have access to both.
I appreciate any input on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

For a 380 watt or so heater, I would use 120 V.  The normal 120 V outlet in the US and Canada can deliver up to 1200 watts.  No need for concern about tripping breakers, as you will be using a much lower current than the usual breakers can supply.

Of course, if you are in an area where the normal outlet is 230 V, you should use a 230 V heater.

Comment: The limit on a 15 A breaker is 1500 watts, actually. (1800 W for pulsed loads, 1500 W for continuous ones)

Comment: I was thinking the same. Thank you both!